# ActiveRecord.establish_connection concurrency across requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, database-connection

Using Rails, is this approach vulnerable to causing separate, concurrent requests to use the wrong connection/database?

﻿  def find_user

```
@user= User.find_by_email(email)

unless @user
  #search non_pro database
  User.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_non_pro".to_sym)

 @user= User.find_by_email(email)
end
```

ensure
    User.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}".to_sym)
  end

What I want to know is if a first request causes the connection to be established with 'non_pro', will a second separate request run the risk of incorrectly connecting to 'non_pro' if it runs while the first is connected to 'non_pro'

Answer (score 0):

I did a small test and found out that if you do `User.establish_connection()` this will change the connection globally for all concurrent requests, so they might fail by using the wrong database.

What you can do is making a subclass of User

```
class NonProUser < User
    self.table_name = "users"
    establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_non_pro".to_sym)
end
```

Then you can use `NonProUser.find_by_email(email)` to find your user on the other database.